# BigQuery no matching signature when trying to filter rows based on on list of integers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract certain rows where the column Code matches one of the integers in a list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `detail_table`
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-03-12' AND '2019-03-15'
AND Code IN UNNEST([36516, 152])
```

However, I get the error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 No matching signature for
>   operator IN UNNEST for argument types: STRING, ARRAY

What am I supposed to do to make it work? When its strings then it works fine, but I have to filter on integers.

Comment: Is `Code` a string representation of integers? If it is, you could `CAST(Code AS INT64)`.

Comment: Code is indeed string, I thought it was a number as it had only numbers, but the table was stored as a string... thats why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below instead

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `project.dataset.detail_table`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019-03-12' AND '2019-03-15'
AND Code IN UNNEST(['36516', '152'])
```

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `project.dataset.detail_table`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019-03-12' AND '2019-03-15'
AND CAST(Code AS INT64) IN UNNEST([36516, 152])
```

OR even just (depends on your case)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `project.dataset.detail_table`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2019-03-12' AND '2019-03-15'
AND Code IN ('36516', '152')
```